# update record value if contains substring from other column

Tags: sql, database, pattern-matching, postgresql-9.5

I have two tables, one containing all unique towns names in the UK and another one containing the human-inputted country of residence. Of course humans wrote stuff like "london, uk" or "cardiff, united kingdom".

I need to consolidate the country_of_residence column so I have created a table with all possible towns, counties, cities and villages in the UK with almost 9000 records.

I want to update the column `country_of_residence` if its records contain any of the record in the column `entity` in the table `uk_geo_entities`.

I have read a lot answers here but they all try to update by wanting to check against or update *one string*, I need to do this against every record of a column.

```
a_table                          uk_geo_entities

country_of_residence | ...       entity | ...        
-------------------- + ...       ------ + ...
london, uk                       london
cardiff, england                 cardiff


UPDATE a_table
SET country_of_residence = 'united kingdom'
FROM (SELECT entity
      FROM uk_geo_entities) b
WHERE country_of_residence LIKE '%'||b.entity||'%';
```

and

```
UPDATE psc_sharing_dodgy_officers
SET country_of_residence = 'united kingdom'
WHERE country_of_residence LIKE '%'||(SELECT entity FROM 
uk_geo_entities)||'%';
```

run, but nothing happens.

After a working query I'd need to see

```
a_table                         

country_of_residence | ...          
-------------------- + ...     
united kingdom                       
united kingdom
```

Comment: And is `"New York"` supposed to match "York"?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being specific - I have already weeded out from the list all entities which are known to have duplicates in other countries cities - so `york` is not present in my list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with EXISTS in the WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE a_table a
SET country_of_residence = 'united kingdom'
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT entity 
  FROM uk_geo_entities
  WHERE a.country_of_residence LIKE '%' || entity || '%'
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=57b88c115bd9be27ccbcfb7079bf3cc1).

Comment: It didn't work - I deleted the `a` from `a.country_of_residence` after `update` cuz i got an error `column a ... does not exist`.